# How to set $fillable attributes for another table with hasOne relationship in a Laravel/Ardent model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, ardent

Suppose, I have these ardent models

```
class User extends \LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent
{
     public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;
     protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'address');
     protected $table = 'Users';
     public static $relationsData = array(
     'location'  => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Location');
}

class Location extends \LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent
{
     protected $fillable = array('address');
     protected $table = 'Locations';         
}
```

Now, when I write a controller code like this,

```
 $user = new User;
 $user->address = Input::get('address');
 $user->push();
```

It doesn't save the address data to address table

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the `Party` model?

Furthermore, `Input::get('address')` does nothing, it just returns the address from the input.

I'm assuming here, but I suppose you'd want something like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->locations()->create(Input::only('address'));
```

That will create a new location for the user, passing in the address from the input.

---

If you're trying to use Ardent's autohydration, this might do the trick:

```
// Autohydrate the location model with input.
$location = new Location;

// Associate the new model with your user.
$user->locations()->save($location);
```

Comment: Hi @Dwight, I made necessary corrections in my question. And I used `$user->locations()->create(Input::only('address'));` as you suggested.
But I'm using autohydration (ardent feature) and I thought I do not need to do this manually.
It is still not working as expected.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with Ardent, but I've updated my answer with something that might do the trick.